# Visual Studio 2010 TableLayoutPanel with Buttons events

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, button, tablelayoutpanel

I've made in Visual Studio 2010 in designer mode a TableLayoutPanel (for example 8x8 rowsxcolumns), then I've put in each field of this "matrix" a button. Is there any way how to handle the events centrally? I found that TableLayoutPanel have TabIndexChanged, but I don't know if this will be useful for me.
I'm just trying to find out if is possible this:
I click on second button and get the information on what button I've clicked and will be able to change some of his property - for example icon, or text.
Lets imagine an idea that I will understand tablelayoutpanel as an "matrix" or "array" and I want to work with it something like this:

```
1)I'll click on button on possition i (or i,j)
2)I'll change the Icon of button on possition i (or i,j)
```

Is that possible? If yes, how? 
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a single method handle all your button click events and then use the sender parameter to modify the image on the button.

e.g.

```
private void CreateButtons(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; 8 < length; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; 8 < length; i++)
            {
                var btn = new Button() { Text = "Something" };
                btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
                this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn, i, j);
            }
        }

    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ((Button)sender).Image= SomeMethodThatReturnsAnImage();
    }
```

As an aside the [`TabIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindexchanged.aspx) would be completely useless to you since its only raised when the TabIndex property of a control gets changed which is typically very rare. You'll rember that the TabIndex property is used to control the order of controls for when the user presses the  <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to associate the click event of all your buttons with a single event handler, and then manipulate the clicked button, etc., inside the event handler

Comment: If we mean by "associate" same thing then you've practically just rewritten my question :D
I can have 8x8 buttons, but I can also have 100x100 buttons ...

Comment: I didn't read your question to mean that you had wired up the click events of all buttons to a single handler; I suggested the same solution as Conrad Frix.  Do you want me to go into more detail?